# How to get telegram user's language or country telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I received a list of users from a telegram megagroup. is there a way to see the user's **country or language?** perhaps it can be obtained from the message? can see for which country the megagroup was created, in which the participant will create? Is there any way, any way, to determine the country or member of Telegram users using telethon? Thanks!